# How can I install pybrain on Mac OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: python, macos, pybrain

How can I install pybrain on Mac OS X Mountain Lion? I've already installed Python.

Comment: Michael Petrotta, I love your editing style.

Comment: Have you tried the basic pip install? Seriously, without knowing what you've tried, I can't decide what answers to eliminate from suggesting to you

Comment: all i did was to set up and install Python 2.7.5 from python homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Python package manager `pip` with the correct permissions:

```
pip install pybrain
```

or `clone` the repo and build the package

```
git clone git://github.com/pybrain/pybrain.git
python setup.py install
```

Comment: thanks for help, but it says pip command was not found. Does anybody know what this means?

Comment: And when I included sudo before pip, the message like this came out:

Comment: WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss
or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your
typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.
To proceed, enter your password, or type Ctrl-C to abort.

Comment: and then there was password to be typed, but it was not even typed at all. I think I am stuck somewhere

Comment: Oh yeah you va to install pip to install it do this `sudo easy_install pip `

Comment: Thanks, but again, another warning message, and the password thing came out